# 403 Forbidden Mediawiki when using HTML attributes

Tags: html, mediawiki

I am very new to web hosting and have recently set up a vanilla install of Mediawiki (https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki). For the most part everything seems to be working just fine.

However while I was editing a particular page, after saving, I was presented with a 403 Forbidden error:

[image: 403 Forbidden]

At the time I thought it was because I had a table on the page I was doing something similar to this example:

```
{| class="wikitable"
 !colspan="6"|Shopping List
 |-
 |rowspan="2"|Bread & Butter
 |Pie
 |Buns
 |Danish
 |colspan="2"|Croissant
 |-
 |Cheese
 |colspan="2"|Ice cream
 |Butter
 |Yogurt
 |}
```

Out of curiosity I removed the HTML attributes (colspan and rowspan) and everything worked fine, see the working code below:

```
{| class="wikitable"
 |+Food complements
 |-
 |Orange
 |Apple
 |-
 |Bread
 |Pie
 |-
 |Butter
 |Ice cream   
 |}
```

This has led me to conclude that there seems to be some sort error on submitting HTML related data to the database?

I have been looking around for a couple of days but I could not seem to find anyone that was having the same issue as me, I assume it has something to do with my host but I am really not too sure.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated, feel free to ask for any information I have failed to provide. Thank you very much.

PS: I also seem to get this error when access the "User" namespace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is nothing special that can cause this problem in markup I guess that reason of 403 status is **LifeSpeed** web-server you're using. You can try to check your settings at `Admin Console => Configuration => Server => Security`, however, best solution here is to use **Apache** instead of LifeSpeed.